# "Call it a day" — is it positive?

Tags: meaning, idioms, connotation

I'm not a native speaker. Someone told my boss about my work, 'He called it a day'. Is it a rather neutral expression about ending some day work, or does it mean 'he's lazy and didn't finish it'?

Comment: That would really depend on the context since that expression can be used in both a positive and negative light.  Was is said after a 12-hour day where you beat your head against the wall trying to solve a tricky problem and finally "called it a day"?  (That would be positive).  Or was it said after you took a 2-hour lunch, clocked back in, played a round of Angry Birds then left for the day?  (That would be negative).

Comment: There's nowhere near enough context to say what the boss meant. Perhaps OP has been working there "on probation" for a few weeks, and has made several mistakes. In which case perhaps the boss has finally decided to "call it a day" and give OP notice to quit.

Answer (score 3):

It means that he’s had ***more* than enough work for the day**, and that he was therefore stopping. It has a connotation of having worked hard, and that that was enough for now.

Comment: I often hear/use it in contexts with no connection to *work*, or specifically to having done enough *on that particular day*. For example, *"Let's call it a day and get divorced"* sounds like a perfectly normal usage to me.

Comment: And it doesn't necessarily refer only to a *day*. In both of @FumbleFingers comments, it clearly just refers to a period of time at which you decide to call an *end* to that particular activity.

Comment: I read it as the coworker being sarcastic or negative (_"his work isn't up to snuff because he called it a day_")—perhaps similar to "phoning it in"—but this answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

It means : to stop work or other activity.
It could be a neutral expression.

References: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/called+it+a+day

Answer (score 1):

*Call it a day* is an idiomatic phrase meaning to stop working for the day. From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/call_it_a_day):

> 1. (idiomatic) To retire. "After suffering massive losses for three years in a row, the boss decided to call it a day, and sold his company."
> 2. (idiomatic) To cease the activity for the day.

In and of itself, *call it a day* is not inherently negative. However, if your coworker told your boss that you "called it a day" with respect to your work, he might have meant that you slacked off; *i.e.*, you didn't work on the project as much as you could have, or you handed in unfinished work, or you literally left the office before finishing your work. In these cases, your coworker's pronouncement could have been negative in nature. It's hard to say without a bit more context.